# regex - brackets and parenthesis in character-class

Tags: regex, grep, special-characters

I would like to match these characters: [ ] ( ) in a character class in a regex, how can I do that?

```
echo 'some text (some text in parenthesis) [some other in brackets]' | grep '[\[\]\(\)]'
```

This one doesn't match any character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
echo 'some text (some text in paranthesis) [some other in brackets]' |
grep -o '[][()]'

(
)
[
]
```

Please note that:

- If `]` and `[` are placed right after opening `[` in a bracket expression then they are treated as literals `]` or `[`.
- That may be an optional `^` at the first place for negation before `]` or `[`
- You don't need to escape `(` and `)` inside a bracket expression.

Comment: Anubhava: 9.6 answers per day for 5 and a half years. I want a job at AOL too!

Comment: Lol  sure come on board

Comment: `[][()]` is a bracket expression, not a character class. `[:space:]` is a character class and so can be included in a bracket expression as `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: @EdMorton The Rust documentation calls them character classes: https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/#character-classes. The Perl Docs call them "Bracketed Character Classes": https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass#Bracketed-Character-Classes. I gave you +1 for precision efforts, much appreciated.

Comment: @JonathanKomar yeah, I know there's other muddy terminology out there, some of which refers to `[...]` as a character class and `[:space:]` as a "POSIX character class" and/or mixes up terminology and confuses everyone by calling both `[:space:]` and `[[:space:]]` a "character class" (see https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html) but here we're talking about `grep` here which is a mandatory POSIX tool and per POSIX `[...]` is simply a bracket expression, `[:space:]` is simply a character class, and `[[:space:]]` is simply a bracket expression that contains a character class.

Answer (score 3):

Just FYI:

Accoding to the [`grep` documentation, section *3.2 Character Classes and Bracket Expressions*](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html):

> Most meta-characters lose their special meaning inside bracket expressions.
>
> `‘]’`
>   ends the bracket expression if it’s not the first list item. So, if you want to make the ‘]’ character a list item, you must put it first.

Also, you can see that `(`, `[` and `)` are not special in the bracket expressions.

Since `]` in your `'[\[\]\(\)]'` *bracket expression* pattern is not the first character, it ends the pattern, and the next `]` created an incomplete bracket expression.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way is to put a \ before the character, but oddly enough that doesn't seem to work for ] with grep.

If you can use Perl, do this:

```
% cat yourfile.txt | perl -ne 'print if(/[\[\]\(\)]/);';
```